# Wrapping words in a sentence using regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm converting sentences like:

```
Phasellus turpis, elit. Tempor et lobortis? Venenatis: sed enim!
```

to:

```
_________ ______, ____. ______ __ ________? _________: ___ ____!
```

using:

```
utf8_encode(preg_replace("/[^.,:;!?¿¡ ]/", "_", utf8_decode($ss->phrase) ))
```

But I'm facing a problem: Google is indexing all those empty words as keywords. I'd like to convert the original strings to something invisible to Google, like:

```
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</span>, ....
```

using:

```
.parent span { text-decoration:underline; }
```

that is, wrapping words inside span tags, replacing words' characters with &nbsp ; and leaving untouched the special characters .,:;!?¿¡ and space.

Is this possible to solve using a regex? I actually solved this by using a non very efficient loop that scans every character of the string, but I must scan many sentences per page.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `preg_replace("/[^.,:;!?¿¡ ]/", "&nbsp;", ...);` ?

Comment: @cegfault, that preg_replace is working fine, but I prefer to use text-decoration:underline instead of underscore because those "underscore words" are being indexed by Google as keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use preg_replace_callback and have the callback create the appropriate replacement.  Something along the lines of (untested)

```
function replacer($match) {
    return "<span>".str_repeat("&nbsp;",strlen($match[1]))."</span>";
}

// Note the addition of the () and the + near the end of the regex
utf8_encode(preg_replace_callback("/([^.,:;!?¿¡ ]+)/", "replacer", utf8_decode($ss->phrase) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourphrase = preg_replace('/([^\W]+)/si', '<span>$1</span>', $yourphrase);
```

this will wrap all the "**_**"-words with spans...

imho you need a two-step procedure here, first you have to convert the letters to underscore (which obvious work already?),
second you'll have to wrap the "*_*"-words in a span (with mine regex).